# approximating to delta sequence

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove the following:

Let $h_{n}(t)=\sqrt {n}e^{-nt^{2}}$. The area under the graph of $h_{n}(t)$ is $\sqrt {\pi}$ and for any $\epsilon>0$ $h_{n}(t) \rightarrow0$ uniformly outside $]-\epsilon, \epsilon [$.

Show that if $g(t)$ is continuous and $0<N< \infty$ then $\int_{-N}^{N} g(t)h_{n}(t)dt \rightarrow g(0)\sqrt{\pi} $

I try to use the fact that we can approach to the function g by sequence of polynomials but I couldnt get the result. Any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

$$I_n = \int_{-N}^{N}g(t) \sqrt{n}e^{-nt^2}\,dt.$$

Note that

$$g(0)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sqrt{n}e^{-nt^2}\,dt= \sqrt{\pi}g(0).$$

Hence, using the change of variables $u = \sqrt{n}t$,

$$|I_n - \sqrt{\pi}g(0)| \\ \leqslant \int_{-N}^{N}|g(t)-g(0)| \sqrt{n}e^{-nt^2}\,dt + |g(0)|\int_{N}^{\infty} \sqrt{n}e^{-nt^2}\,dt + |g(0)|\int_{-\infty}^{-N} \sqrt{n}e^{-nt^2}\,dt \\ \leqslant \int_{-N}^{N}|g(t)-g(0)| \sqrt{n}e^{-nt^2}\,dt + |g(0)|\int_{N\sqrt{n}}^{\infty} e^{-u^2}\,du + |g(0)|\int_{-\infty}^{-N\sqrt{n}}e^{-u^2}\,du .$$

As $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-u^2} \, du < \infty$, the second and third terms on the RHS are each less than $\epsilon/3$ if $n$ is sufficiently large, and

$$|I_n - \sqrt{\pi}g(0)|  \leqslant  \int_{-N}^{N}|g(t)-g(0)| \sqrt{n}e^{-nt^2}\,dt +\frac{2\epsilon}{3}.$$

Since $g$ is continuous on $[-N,N]$ it is bounded and $|g(t)| \leqslant M$. Also there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|g(t) - g(0)| < \epsilon/9\sqrt{\pi}$ when $|t| < \delta.$

Hence,

$$\int_{-N}^{N}|g(t)-g(0)| \sqrt{n}e^{-nt^2}\,dt  \\ < \frac{\epsilon}{9\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\delta}^{\delta} \sqrt{n}e^{-nt^2}\,dt + 2M \int_{\delta}^{N} \sqrt{n}e^{-nt^2}\,dt + 2M \int_{-N}^{-\delta} \sqrt{n}e^{-nt^2}\,dt \\ < \frac{\epsilon}{9} + 2M \int_{\delta\sqrt{n}}^{N\sqrt{n}} e^{-u^2}\,du + 2M \int_{-N\sqrt{n}}^{-\delta\sqrt{n}} e^{-u^2}\,du.$$

If $n$ is sufficiently large then the two integrals on the RHS are each less than $\epsilon/ 18M$, and

$$\int_{-N}^{N}|g(t)-g(0)| \sqrt{n}e^{-nt^2}\,dt  < \frac{\epsilon}{3}.$$

Therefore, if $n$ is sufficiently large

$$|I_n - \sqrt{\pi}g(0)| < \epsilon.$$

Comment: Great!.Thank you very much.

Comment: @user135582: You are welcome.

Comment: One more thing is it true that if $g$ is continuous and bounded then $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)h_{n}(t) \rightarrow g(0)\sqrt {n}$ as $n\rightarrow 0$?

Comment: You can prove $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(t)h_{n}(t) \rightarrow g(0)\sqrt{\pi}$ as $n \to \infty$ if $g$ is bounded and uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.  Without uniform continuity it may not be true.

Comment: I just realized, sorry and thanks..